# Conditional Include() in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have seen a few answers to similar questions, however I cannot seem to work out how to apply the answer to my issue.

```
var allposts = _context.Posts
            .Include(p => p.Comments)
            .Include(aa => aa.Attachments)
            .Include(a => a.PostAuthor)
            .Where(t => t.PostAuthor.Id == postAuthorId).ToList();
```

Attachments can be uploaded by the Author (type Author) or Contributor (type Contributor). What I want to do, is only get the Attachments where the owner of the attachment is of type Author.

I know this doesn't work and gives an error:

```
.Include(s=>aa.Attachments.Where(o=>o.Owner is Author))
```

I've read about Filtered Projection here

EDIT - link to article:
: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/10/13/tip-37-how-to-do-a-conditional-include.aspx,

but I just can't get my head around it.

I don't want to include the filter in the final where clause as I want ALL posts, but I only want to retrieve the attachments for those posts that belong to the Author.

EDIT 2: - Post schema requested

```
public abstract class Post : IPostable
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    public Person PostAuthor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `Posts` schema please?

Comment: @DarkKnight - see edit

Comment: @grayson What you're asking to do is not possible. `Linq2Sql` will convert your code into raw `SQL`, and it'll return child rows via a join. You can't do this kind of conditional join in `SQL`. Your only option is to remove `.Include(aa => aa.Attachments)`, and have a second query which returns attachments depending on whether or not the owner is an author/contributor.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the link you posted I can confirm that trick works but for one-many (or many-one) relationship only. In this case your `Post-Attachment` should be one-many relationship, so it's totally applicable. Here is the query you should have:

```
//this should be disabled temporarily
_context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var allposts = _context.Posts.Where(t => t.PostAuthor.Id == postAuthorId)
                       .Select(e => new {
                           e,//for later projection
                           e.Comments,//cache Comments
                           //cache filtered Attachments
                           Attachments = e.Attachments.Where(a => a.Owner is Author),
                           e.PostAuthor//cache PostAuthor
                        })
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(e => e.e).ToList();
```

Comment: do I need to add "_context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;" to renable lazy loading after this call?

Comment: @grayson yes, if you want to re-enable that.

Comment: @Hopeless know this question is old, but my recent questions was marked as duplicate to this one, my requirement is when `Attachments` has additional child properties they are not being available in result.  Link to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347487/unable-to-write-an-include-query-with-firstordefault-and-condition

Comment: @Krtti I'm not so sure if your issue can be solved with what answered here, actually I don't understand your issue well (from what you described in the linked question, there are at least 2 ways of understanding). Also someone added an answer there and looks like it's correct for one way of understanding the issue. The idea in my answer is just simple enough to apply, when it's not working maybe it's not applicable. Finally it's a long time I've not been working with EF and Linq-to-entity, so I may not help you much.

Comment: @Hopeless no worries, my question was answered and thanks for taking time to inform

Comment: And one more thing, can I have Include statement for the tables on which Foreign key is not defined but they have common Columns that actually we can bring in? I mean they are related tables but not actually foreign key defined on them, can I use those tables also in Include statement - thank you for all this support - its a great help guys.

Answer (score 60):

EF Core 5.0 is introducing Filtered Include soon.

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(e => e.Posts.Where(p => p.Title.Contains("Cheese")))
    .ToList();
```

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `virtual` keyword from your `Attachments` navigation property to prevent lazy loading:

`public ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }`

First method: Issue two separate queries: one for the Posts, one for the Attachments, and let relationship fix-up do the rest:

```
List<Post> postsWithAuthoredAttachments = _context.Posts
    .Include(p => p.Comments) 
    .Include(p => p.PostAuthor)
    .Where(p => p.PostAuthor.Id == postAuthorId)
    .ToList();

List<Attachment> filteredAttachments = _context.Attachments
    .Where(a => a.Post.PostAuthor.Id == postAuthorId)
    .Where(a => a.Owner is Author)
    .ToList()
```

Relationship fixup means that you can access these filtered Attachments via a Post's navigation property

Second method: one query to the database followed by an in-memory query:

```
var query = _context.Posts
    .Include(p => p.Comments) 
    .Include(p => p.PostAuthor)
    .Where(p => p.PostAuthor.Id == postAuthorId)
    .Select(p => new 
        {
            Post = p,
            AuthoredAttachments = p.Attachments
                Where(a => a.Owner is Author)
        }
    );
```

I would just use the anonymous type here

```
var postsWithAuthoredAttachments = query.ToList()
```

or I would create a ViewModel class to avoid the anonymous type:

```
List<MyDisplayTemplate> postsWithAuthoredAttachments = 
     //query as above but use new PostWithAuthoredAttachments in the Select
```

Or, if you really want to unwrap the Posts:

```
List<Post> postsWithAuthoredAttachments = query.//you could "inline" this variable
    .AsEnumerable() //force the database query to run as is - pulling data into memory
    .Select(p => p) //unwrap the Posts from the in-memory results
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this implementation](http://blog.cincura.net/232741-include-with-filtering-or-limiting/) of an extension method (eg.) `Include2()`. After that, you can call:

```
_context.Posts.Include2(post => post.Attachments.Where(a => a.OwnerId == 1))
```

The code above includes only attachments where `Attachment.OwnerId == 1`.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't appear to work when there are no Attachments for a post. A, I missing something

Answer (score 2):

For net core

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit

```
var allposts = _context.Posts
        .Include(p => p.Comments)
        .Include(a => a.PostAuthor)
        .Where(t => t.PostAuthor.Id == postAuthorId).ToList();

_context.Entry(allposts)
        .Collection(e => e.Attachments)
        .Query()
        .Where(e=> e.Owner is Author)
        .Load();
```

it makes 2 query to sql.

Comment: This i not working cause you try to use explicit loading on a list of posts. But the .Entry() can only be used on a single entity.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var allposts = _context.Posts
        .Include(p => p.Comments)
        .Include(a => a.PostAuthor)
        .Where(t => t.PostAuthor.Id == postAuthorId).ToList();

_context.Attachments.Where(o=>o.Owner is Author).ToList();
```

Answer (score -5):

Assuming "a" being of type "YourType", a conditonal include could be solved by using a method extension, e.g.

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ConditionalInclude<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, bool include) where T : YourType
    {
        if (include)
        {
            return source
                .Include(a => a.Attachments)
                .Include(a => a.Attachments.Owner));
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

... then just use this like you are using .Include, e.g.

```
bool yourCondition;

.ConditionalInclude(yourCondition)
```

Comment: is this a joke or something?

Comment: Thats genius..!

Comment: This helped me!