# Entity Framework SQL query not returning correct data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am using EF6 and have a query using projection. I got the code from a question I asked [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32753050/3482632)

This code works perfectly, however it generates over 1200 lines of SQL and on first call, it is taking over 5 seconds to compile the query and 300ms to execute it, which is not acceptable. You can see what I mean [here:](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/26689/20151124-ayn7-63kb.jpg)

I used Glimpse to see what the SQL it was generating and interestingly noticed that if I remove comments, the SQL goes down to just 200 lines of code.

I decided to place the SQL into a stored procedure and although it returns the posts data correctly, the PostAuthor is not being populated.

I double checked and with the Linq query it is populated, but using

```
_context.Posts.SqlQuery(...)
```

the PostAuthor object is not being populated.

I also double checked the raw SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio and all the data is being returned, it is just not being populated when it returns.

Am I missing something? Is this a known issue?

Comment: You might need to show some code to help. What is the C# LINQ query you are using? What is the SQL of the generated query in Glimpse? What is in the dots in your alternative solution?

Comment: If I recall correctly (because I don't use stored procs like that), it's a known issue based on some other threads I've read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var allposts = _context.Posts
  .Include(p=>p.Comments)
  .Include(p=>p.Attachments)
  .Where(t => t.PostAuthor.Id == postAuthorId)
  .ToList();
```

Of course, posting the SQL could help in determining if there might be a better approach to retrieving your data as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I need to only get comments with a particular sender and attachments with a particular owner so I cant use this. This was the basis of my other question,

Comment: And is it faster than the above?